# Is there a way to cache and filter a table locally in PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I’m faced with having to process a table in ORACLE 11g, that contains around 5 million records.   These records are speed limits along a divided highway.  There is a SpeedLimitId, HighwayId and a from mile post and to mile post to depict the area that the speed limit is applied to.  Currently all the records are only on one side of the divided highway and the records need to be processed to also apply them to the other side.  There is a measure equation table that lets us know which range of measure on one side of the highway equal a range of measure on the other side of the highway.  This allows us to calculate the measure that the speed limit event will be on the other side by calculating the percentage of the measure value in the range on measure and then finding that same percentage of the range on the opposing side.  The speed limit record can be contained to one measure equation record or it can cross several of them.  Base on the information in the speed limit table and the measure equation, one or more records need to be inserted into a third table.

SPEED_LIMIT

```
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
| SpeedLimitId | HighwayId | FromMilePost | ToMilePost | SpeedLimit | Lane  |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
|            1 | 75N       |          115 |        123 |         60 | South |
+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+------------+-------+
```

MEASURE_EQUATION

```
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------------+
| EquationId | NorthHighwayId | NFromMile | NToMile | NGain | SouthHighwayId | SFromMile | SToMile | SGain | IsHighwayDivided |
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------------+
|          1 | 75N            |       105 |     120 |    15 | 75S            |       100 |     110 |    10 | No               |
|          2 | 75N            |       120 |     125 |     5 | 75S            |       110 |     125 |    15 | Yes              |
|          3 | 75N            |       125 |     130 |     5 | 75S            |       125 |     130 |     5 | No               |
+------------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+----------------+-----------+---------+-------+------------------+
```

Depending on information in the SPEED_LIMIT and MEASURE_EQUATION table there will be a need to insert at least one but can be as many as three records in a third table.  There are a dozen or so different scenarios that can take place as a result of different values in the fields.
Using the above data you can see that the SpeedLimitId 1 is noted as being on the south side of the highway, but it is currently on the north side and that it also spans the 2 equation records with the ids of 1 and 2.  In this case it spans two measure ranges as a single roadway splits off and becomes divided highway.  We need to split the original records into two events and add them to third processing table and calculate the new measure for the south bound lane.

SPEED_LIMIT_PROCESSING

```
+--------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------+
| SpeedLimitId | HighwayId | LANE  | FromMile | ToMile |
+--------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------+
|            1 | 75N       | North |      115 |    120 |
|            1 | 75S       | South |      110 |    119 |
+--------------+-----------+-------+----------+--------+
```

The methodology to calculate the measure on the south bound lane is as follows:

```
+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|                    |  From Measure Translation  |   To Measure Translation    |
+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Event Measure as % | ((120 – 120)/5) * 100 = 0% | ((123 – 120)/5) * 100 = 60% |
| Offset Measure     | ((15 * 0) / 100 = 0        | ((15 * 60) / 100) = 9       |
| Translated Measure | 110 + 0 = 110              | 110 + 9 = 119               |
+--------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

My concern is to do this in the most efficient way possible.  The idea would be to loop through each record in the SPEED_LIMIT table, select the corresponding records in the measure equation table and then based on information from those 2 tables I would insert records into a 3rd table.  In order to limit PL/SQL context switches I planned on using "BULK COLLECT and FORALL” statements to query the event table and to run the insert statements, this would allow me to do things in batches.  The missing component is how to get the corresponding records from the MEASURE_EQUATION table without having to do a sql query for every record loop in the SPEED_LIMIT table.  The MEASURE_EQUATION only has about 700 records in it, so I was wondering if there is a way I can cache it in PL SQL and then filter it to the appropriate records for the current SPEED_LIMIT record.

As you can probably gleamed from my question, I’m fairly new at PL SQL and ORACLE in general, so maybe I’m going about it in the completely wrong way.

Comment: You want to do all 5 million rows at once?  Is this a one-time operation?  If so, forget about PL/SQL, and "looping / for each row" logic.  Rearrange your question to clarify exactly how you want the output to look.  It's almost certain it can be done in SQL and, again, almost certain that a pure-SQL solution will blow the doors off anything you'd do in PL/SQL.

Comment: Please edit and add your expected output for the example data. What should the third table look like after your script is run? Do you expect 2 rows for the 75S 16-30m segment, and if so, will the 2 rows have the same mile markers, or be split somehow?

Comment: Referring to your concern  "The MEASURE_EQUATION only has about 700 records in it, so I was wondering if there is a way I can cache ..." If this is often needed Oracle tends to do so automatically, esp given the small size. Look up "cache hit ratio".